# display: inline doesn't work properly with div

Tags: html, css

I'm a HTML/CSS beginner and currently I'm building a simple website. What I wanna do is I'd like to make 3 divs. One for the whole site, one for the content and one for the navigation list - row.

It should look like this:

_ _ _ _ _ _ (navigation list - row)

asdfwefwefwe

cofwerferwefw (content)

To recognize the divs I background-colored them. Whenever I use display-inline it looks like this. whole site div(red colored), main content(orange colored)

http://puu.sh/iFyeC/a48443bc07.png

When I use display: inline-block whole site div(red colored), main content(orange colored), navigation list - row(blue colored)

http://puu.sh/iFyil/40e73716e7.png

Now it works but I want a navigation - row bar and not a ranked list but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my css for the navigation list - row:

```
.navigationlist{
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Thank you very much for reading and for hopefully good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from using the li and ul I will suggest you make use of the bootstrap navbar class whenever you have to create navigation bars. You can read on its advantages online (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) plus it will also allow you to highlight one of the li by default. In your case it would be something like.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">World</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Use Home,Story,Hereos All in list tag!!

```
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Story</li>
<li>Hereos</li<
......
<ul>
```

And then Style Then element

```
li
{
display:inline;
padding:10px;
}
```

Your Out will be 
http://myslambook.pe.hu/demo.png

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0.4em;
    margin: 1% auto;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Stack Overflow</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```